# Retorno de uma consulta Knex usando .map

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, oracle, knex.js

Boa tarde pessoal. Tenho um Controller que recebe dados de uma planilha do frontend, le os dados e joga estes para rodar uma query no banco, com isso meu intuito é jogar os resultados de volta para o usuário. Mas estou tendo problema tentando realizar a consulta dentro de um .map utilizando o Knex. A consulta é realizada normalmente, a query receber os valores do map mas o problema ocorre quando eu tento " retornar " os valores obtidos nas pesquisas para alguma variavel ou afins, pois não consigo atribuir o valor para nada do tipo. No `.then` se eu colocar um `console.log(response)` ele aparece os valores, mesmo que de forma duplicada. Já tentei dar um `.push` na let teste ali dentro também ou até mesmo uma function passando a variavel por parametros, mas nada que eu consiga retornar o valor para o client no `return res.json()` , pois a variavel chega vazia para o frontend. Alguem sabe o que eu posso fazer para conseguir atribuir o valor a algo e enviar para o client ? OBS: É um banco Oracle.

mainController.js:

```
const knexOra = require('../database/oracle');

module.exports = {

  async index(req, res) {

    const { info } = req.body;

    let teste = [];

    let query = await info.map(async item => {
      try {
        let response = await knexOra.raw(`SELECT a.nrocheckout as NROPDV, a.nroempresa, c.numerodf as NROCUPOM,  to_char(a.dtahoremissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as DTAEMISSAO, a.vlrtotal as Valor
        FROM consincomonitor.tb_doctopagto a, consincomonitor.tb_docto b, mfl_doctofiscal c, mfl_dfitem d 
        WHERE a.seqdocto = b.seqdocto
        and a.nroempresa = b.nroempresa
        and a.nroempresa = c.nroempresa
        and a.nroempresa = d.nroempresa
        and b.nroempresa = c.nroempresa
        and b.nroempresa = d.nroempresa
        and a.nrocheckout = b.nrocheckout
        and c.nroempresa = d.nroempresa
        and c.nrocheckout = a.nrocheckout
        and c.nrocheckout = b.nrocheckout
        and a.nroformapagto = c.nroformapagto
        and c.numerodf = d.numerodf
        and c.seriedf = d.seriedf
        and c.nroserieecf = d.nroserieecf
        and to_char(a.dtahoremissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_char(c.dtahoremissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        and b.dtamovimento = c.dtamovimento
        and a.codautorizacaotef = ?
        and a.nroempresa = ?
        GROUP BY a.nrocheckout, a.nroempresa, c.numerodf, a.vlrtotal, a.dtahoremissao
        having sum(d.vlritem) = a.vlrtotal
        `, [item[1], item[0]]).then(response => {
          return response;
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    console.log(query);

    return res.status(200).json(teste);
  }
}
```

Comment: Em vez de `let response = await knexOra.raw(...` testa com `return await knexOra.raw(...`.

Comment: Boa tarde @Sergio♦, eu fiz esse teste anteriormente também, o resultado que ele tem no backend é uma ```Promise <Pending>```, só que como é em um map aparece 4 destas, que é o total de vezes que ele roda a query.

Comment: Sabes como usar `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas coisas c considerar:

Esse método/função `index` não parece precisar de retorno, pois estás a enviar a resposta dentro dela. Nesse caso `async` não é preciso e podes tratar tudo "à moda de promises". Corre o `.map` que retorna promises, e depois passa essa array de promises ao `Promise.all` que será chamado quando todas resolverem. Aí podes passar essa array de respostas ao `res.json(`.

Exemplo:

```js
const knexOra = require("../database/oracle");

module.exports = {
  index(req, res) {
    const { info } = req.body;
    const queries = info.map((item) => {
      return knexOra.raw(
        `SELECT a.nrocheckout as NROPDV, a.nroempresa, c.numerodf as NROCUPOM,  to_char(a.dtahoremissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as DTAEMISSAO, a.vlrtotal as Valor
        FROM consincomonitor.tb_doctopagto a, consincomonitor.tb_docto b, mfl_doctofiscal c, mfl_dfitem d
        WHERE a.seqdocto = b.seqdocto
        and a.nroempresa = b.nroempresa
        and a.nroempresa = c.nroempresa
        and a.nroempresa = d.nroempresa
        and b.nroempresa = c.nroempresa
        and b.nroempresa = d.nroempresa
        and a.nrocheckout = b.nrocheckout
        and c.nroempresa = d.nroempresa
        and c.nrocheckout = a.nrocheckout
        and c.nrocheckout = b.nrocheckout
        and a.nroformapagto = c.nroformapagto
        and c.numerodf = d.numerodf
        and c.seriedf = d.seriedf
        and c.nroserieecf = d.nroserieecf
        and to_char(a.dtahoremissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_char(c.dtahoremissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        and b.dtamovimento = c.dtamovimento
        and a.codautorizacaotef = ?
        and a.nroempresa = ?
        GROUP BY a.nrocheckout, a.nroempresa, c.numerodf, a.vlrtotal, a.dtahoremissao
        having sum(d.vlritem) = a.vlrtotal
        `,
        [item[1], item[0]]
      );
    });

    Promise.all(queries)
      .then((responses) => res.status(200).json(responses))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  },
};
```

Comment: Entendi Sergio, eu não conhecia essa questão do ```Promise.all()```, agradeço muito pela ajuda e pela explicação.

Answer (score -1):

Basta usar await como em
const usuarios = await Usuarios.query()

usuarios.map funcionará normalmente.